# How to make h1 color change when click on it's container?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I click on a container which is also the h1. But I want to do when I click on the container. I want to make its h1 color blue. Im stuck on the part making the h1 blue.

```css
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

// Put event listener on each container
for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
  container[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // This isn't working
      h1[i].style.color = 'blue';
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Neither of the answers that have been posted directly address the issue. They rely on changing the entire color of the `.container` element, or on the `<h1>` always being the immediate first child of `.container`.

The problem that you have is that you have is that your `i` variable is out of scope, and cannot be used inside the event handler you're defining. We can get around this by wrapping the handler function in a closure as follows:

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container'),
    h1        = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++)
{
  container[i].onclick = (function(i) {return function() {
    h1[i].style.color = 'blue';
  };})(i);
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
```

Notice that the above will only change the colour of the `<h1>`. Of course, this assumes that all of your `<h1>` elements are always matched in number and index by the `.container` elements (but I assume that they are, from your question).

Comment: My answer addresses this problem :) ,, Also, you are changing the H1 based on container index which could end-up changing the wrong H1 if a container has no H1 inside it.

Comment: After he replied to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the wrong element when you used `h1[i].style...`
Use `this` instead and it will work fine. See code below:

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

// Put event listener on each container
for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
  container[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Get the 1st H1 inside current container
     this.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.color = 'blue';
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>HELLO</H1>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make the h1 color blue not the container. (h1: color: blue)  Not (container: color: blue)

Comment: @Jeffery  Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

// Put event listener on each container
for(var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
  container[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.firstElementChild.style.color="blue"
  })
}
```

Inside the `container[i].addEventListener('click', ....)` `this` is the HTML Element of the container. Therefore, calling this.firstElementChild will grab the `H1` of that container and change it's color to blue. If you add anything before the `H1`, just call the `children` function on `this` and grab the `h1` element.